# How could I transfer my old OS to my second SSD with 2 SSDs, no HDD, & no DVD boot

Tags: boot, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo laptop which contains the default Windows 7 SSD which altogether is mounted on an ultrabase encapsulated with an expansion bay holding my second Samsung EVO 840 250GB SSD. I do have a DVD read/write drive, but I am only able to either run the DVD expansion bay or the SSD expansion bay at a given time.

My goal is to safely transfer my Windows 7 OS & data onto my second external SSD thereby allowing me to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop SSD.

I am unsure as how to start or accomplish; I imagine a Linux paradise and I am trying to get there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps that may help you:

1. Setup a Live USB stick with your distro of choice.
2. Boot your computer with that Live USB Stick.
3. Once in your distro's desktop you can:

   - Backup your Windows 7 data to your secondary drive.
   - Format your main drive.
   - Install your distro to your newly formatted drive.

This is roughly speaking, the specific steps vary for different distros and your level of understanding of common linux distros usage.